# Delete file after load

Tags: informix

I'm preparing a migration on an Informix database and I'm wondering if it's possible to delete a file after loading its information to a table.

I mean, in theory it should be possible, since you can create it and read it.

If possible I don't want it to remain there occupying needed space.

Comment: There isn't an automatic way to do it.  You can write shell script around the load operations to remove the loaded data file.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to confirm if there was a more direct way to do it. But if that's the case it's not really worth it. Besides I don't really know much about shell commands to feel comfortable to do that. But thanks anyway.